# Mysql - Interpolation from many rows in 1 table using data rows from another table

Tags: mysql, interpolation

I'm trying to return the interpolation results from a table of fans (fandata), with graph data in a different table (datapoint), keyed by fandataid, for airflow at a certain point.

There are 300k fans in fandata.  They can be filtered initially based on fandata.maxaf.
In the example below, I'm looking for a fan which can do airflow > 495 and static pressure > 100.

datapoint has 6 million rows.  The important columns are:

```
INT datapointid
INT fandataid
DOUBLE airflow
DOUBLE staticpressure
DOUBLE efficiency
```

I've come up with a sequence of statements which interpolates staticpressure and efficiency at the given airflow and it works well, except that one section is very slow, because it relies on updating a temporary table with 6 SELECTs for each row.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE calcs (
  `fandataid` INT NOT NULL,
  `af` DOUBLE NULL,
  `sp` DOUBLE NULL,
  `eff` DOUBLE NULL,
  `a1` DOUBLE NULL,
  `s1` DOUBLE NULL,
  `a2` DOUBLE NULL,
  `s2` DOUBLE NULL,
  `e1` DOUBLE NULL,
  `e2` DOUBLE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fandataid`));

/* This seems to work well to create an initial list of fans to work with
by broadly restricting fan type (range) and the maximum airflow and static pressure capabilties of 
the fan we are looking for */
INSERT INTO calcs (fandataid) 
(
SELECT fandataid 
FROM (
SELECT  x.*, ((495- maxaf*0.85) * (sp85-sp35)/maxaf*2 + sp85) as sp   
FROM (  
SELECT fandataid, fandata.maxaf, fandata.sp85, fandata.sp35 
FROM  fandata 
WHERE fandata.built=1 AND fandata.rangeID IN (16,17)  AND fandata.maxaf < 1485 AND fandata.maxaf > 495 
) x  HAVING sp > 50 AND sp < 400 LIMIT 10000 
) y
) ;
```

This next bit is really slooowww....

```
UPDATE calcs LEFT JOIN datapoint ON datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid 
SET 
/* a1, s1 and e1 are values at datapoint below requested airflow */
a1=(SELECT airflow as a1 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow < 495 AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid ORDER BY airflow DESC LIMIT 1),
s1=(SELECT staticpressure as s1 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow < 495 AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid ORDER BY airflow DESC LIMIT 1),
e1=(SELECT efficiency as e1 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow < 495 AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid ORDER BY airflow DESC LIMIT 1),
/* a2, s2 and e2 are values at datapoint above requested airflow */
a2=(SELECT airflow as a2 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow > 495  AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid ORDER BY airflow LIMIT 1),
s2=(SELECT staticpressure as s2 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow > 495 AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid  ORDER BY airflow LIMIT 1),
e2=(SELECT efficiency as e2 FROM datapoint WHERE airflow > 495 AND datapoint.fandataid=calcs.fandataid  ORDER BY airflow LIMIT 1)
;
```

At this point table calcs has many rows like

```
fandataid | af  | sp    | eff | a1  | s1    | a2  | s2  | e1   | e2 
348338    | null| null  | null| 485 | 222.3 | 516 | 211 |65.2  |67.3
```

I then interpolate for sp and eff.

```
/* This is fast */
/* interpolate staticpressure (sp) and efficiciency (eff) at given airflow (495) */
UPDATE calcs SET 
af=495, 
sp = 495 * (s2-s1)/(a2-a1) +s1 - a1*(s2-s1)/(a2-a1),
eff = 495 * (e2-e1)/(a2-a1) +e1 - a1*(e2-e1)/(a2-a1);
```

Now table calcs looks like

```
fandataid | af  | sp    | eff  | a1  | s1    | a2  | s2  | e1   | e2 
348338    | 495 | 218.7 | 65.8 | 485 | 222.3 | 516 | 211 | 65.2 | 67.3
```

Now the user has a sensible list of fans to choose from.

Can anyone please help either speeding up the slow bit, or show me how to use user-defined variables to skip the slow bit altogether...

Comment: You know how global variables are considered bad?  Your database is singleton for your entire system (n hosts) for a given data set (ignoring multi-master but that's a whole different can of worms).  And stored  procedures is a particular hostile way to write and maintain code in case you get tempted.   In other words, don't overlook overlook retrieving the raw data, perform the app logic, then emit the required update statements.  Just figured you may need to hear this.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to avoid retrieving data from Mysql into the app. Currently the system retrieves too much data, and that is where it spends most time.  I figure that if I do the interpolation and filtering within mysql, I can avoid retrieving the details of useless fans.

Comment: If it's an option (new enough mysql) you can use a common table expression instead of a select per field.  Alternatively you can use a view.  I don't know if it would make a difference for performance.

Comment: Instead of `order ... limit 1` have you tried using min/max to identify the row of interest?

Comment: Post a query plan for the slow query

Comment: Are you creating this temporary table every time a user searches for a fan? You should calculate it once (so no temporary) - and then only update it if there is a new fan added to the collection.

Comment: @AllanWind, MysqlWorkbench seems to only show graphical query plans for SELECT.  MIN/MAX only applies to airflow, so is no good for selecting staticpressure at MIN/MAX airflow.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes, for every query.  This is because the airflow of interest ranges from 50 - 14,000 and static pressure of interest from 10 - 1000.

Comment: My point was - why not precompute this table for all possible values and combinations but just once, forever, and then all queries can simply select from it ? Why do you need to compute it every time? Do your fans change their parameters over time?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I get the point. I assumed the resulting table would be too big. I could round the airflows to 100 l/s so there are approx 100 airflows. With up to 1,000 possible fans per airflow, that gives a table of 100,000 rows, which is small enough to be practical. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Still have not come up with any groovy SQL to do what I wanted, but adding staticpressure and efficiency to the index in datapoint so it is (fandataid, airflow, staticpressure, efficiency) took the 917 row UPDATE from 1.0s to 0.3s

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(fandataid, airflow, staticpressure)
```

is my first suggestion.  But let's take it two steps further.

Instead of all those correlated subqueries, use a much simpler `JOIN`:

```
    JOIN ( SELECT  fandataid
                   efficiency as e1, ...
               FROM  datapoint
               WHERE  airflow < 495
               ORDER BY  airflow DESC
               LIMIT  1
         ) AS x  ON  x.fandataid = calcs.fandataid
```

Then have this on `datapoint`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(fandataid, airflow, ...)
```

where the "..." is whatever it takes to make the PK unique.  If you are using an auto_increment (`datapointid`?), then:

```
PRIMARY KEY(fandataid, airflow, datapointid)
INDEX(datapointid)   -- to keep auto_increment happy
```

Then change the `UPDATE` into a "multi-table" update.

A possible trick is to `INSERT` the interpolated values into another temp table.  Then do INSERT..SELECT to copy them into the target table.

(I don't really understand what the Update is for.)

`DOUBLE` is overkill for data like what you have; I suggest `FLOAT`, which has a generous 7 significant digits. in 4 bytes (versus 8).  The space savings will add up; this will help performance slightly.

**2 JOINs**

Now that I see that one set is `<495` and the other is `>495`, I wonder what to do if there is a `=495`.  In any case, there should be 2 `JOINs`, each fetching 3 interesting columns.

(They won't be `CROSS JOIN` since there is an `ON` clause.)

Comment: Hi @Rick, Thanks for the comments.  I do have the required indices, and putting all columns of interest into the index (fandataid,airflow, staticpressure, efficiency) improved the performance significantly, I'll change to FLOAT, as you are right, DOUBLE is not needed.  I can't see how to use your JOIN to UPDATE the multiple columns in calcs, though.  It's the two different SELECTs with < 495 and > 495 which are getting in the way, although I have just learned about CROSS JOIN which might solve that issue.

Comment: @Danny - I added to my Answer.